# Migrating to Firebase Cloud Messaging: What effect will importing an existing Google project have on the project?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

In [setting up FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) it says:

> Create a Firebase project in the Firebase console, if you don't
>   already have one. If you already have an existing Google project
>   associated with your mobile app, click Import Google Project.
>   Otherwise, click Create New Project.

I have an existing GAE cloud endpoints project which currently uses Google Cloud Messaging. I am considering using Firebase Cloud Messaging. I am a little nervous to import that project into the Firebase console because I am not sure what affect this will have on my existing project.

Will my Cloud Endpoints API be managed in the GAE console and my FCM in the Firebase console? I have to look at two consoles now? Like what exactly happens here? I just want to migrate to FCM in my Cloud Endpoints project, I have no intention of using the Firebase database in my app.

Any help or clarification or best-practice much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no changes will happen in your console project. You're not exactly *migrating* the project, only *importing* it in the Firebase Console. The project should stay the same in your GAE console.

You'll have access to other Firebase features, but it's not mandatory (as you probably already know). The *migration* itself is usually applied to the Client apps ([Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) or [iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm)).

Plus from the [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm):

> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure, with new SDKs to make Cloud Messaging development easier.
>
> Benefits of upgrading to FCM SDK include:
>
> - Simpler client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic.
> - An out-of-the-box notification solution. You can use Firebase Notifications, a serverless notifications solution with a web console that lets anyone send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase Analytics insights.
>
> To upgrade from GCM SDKs to FCM SDKs, see the guides for migrating Android and iOS apps.

Comment: Does that answer your question? Or were you looking for some more specific details?

Comment: Knowing that no changes happen to my console project helps. But I am still unsure of what exactly gets imported into the Firebase console? My GCM settings or something? There really aren't any settings besides the API keys I set up. Maybe this is one of those things I just need to try for myself, but I wanted to ask the question first because I wanted to make sure nothing about my existing project, including GCM, would get screwed up.

Comment: And it also seems annoying to have to now manage my FCM in another console... Is there a rhyme or reason for this?

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by *manage my FCM*. I'm aware of accessing the API keys from the console. But AFAIK with FCM, the console is often used for uploading certs (for APNs), accessing the Server key and Sender ID, and getting the `google-services.json` file. Are you doing other actions aside from those when you were just using the GAE console?

Comment: No I wasn't,but it was nice to have it all in one place if you know what I mean... I just don't see what other bonuses there are for using the Firebase console as of now.

Comment: I get what you mean. I guess it's also just a way to introduce Firebase to most developers. Give it a chance though. You might find the Firebase notification console useful one of these days. Cheers! :)