# Update new APNS certificate to GCM

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, p12

Generated new certificates in Apple Developer Centre. 
It's weird i couldn't upload that certificates to GCM and also i couldn't see UPDATE button developer website.

It shows error {{ controller.errorMessage }}

How do I do that? Here's a screenshot of the Google Developer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would have to import your GCM project to the Firebase Console (there won't be any changes, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710079/4625829)) and update the certs from there.

While already importing, I would strongly advise toigrate your app(s) to start using FCM.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I was facing and able to solve !

**Background** : In my scenario we have an iOS App in the store and all our push notification configured through Google GCM (*We were not using FCM*). But we had situation where our APNS certificate is just about to get expired and we don't want to make any iOS Release(*We had around 4k DAU on the current version*)

Once certificate was expired any Notification we sent was throwing `InvalidApnsCredential`from GCM.

Here is how to get out of this.

1. Configure you Firebase project. (Make sure you're logged into right Google account - the one you configured for setting up your GCM)

   Goto : https://firebase.google.com > GET STARTED
2. Choose **Import Google Project**
   [image]
3. You must see now all the GCM Project as below - If your logged in with correct account.
   Choose the project.
   [image]
4. Now your Firebase project is ready. It should look like below.
   [image]
5. To Update new certificate.

   - Choose Setting gear at Overview.
   - Choose Project Settings
     [image]
6. Now choose **Cloud Messaging** Tab & now you **APNs Certificate** section is visible.

   - If Certificate already expired - you must see RED flagged cell with *UPLOAD* & *DELETE* options. Upload new APNs certificate using * UPLOAD*.

[image]

You got better way to do it, please share your thoughts ! Cheers !