# GCM Web Page to add certificates

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, certificate, firebase-cloud-messaging

Some GCM push notifications certificates where expired. I have renew the certificates i iOS but notifications doesn't arrive. Then I have gone to the web https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?refresh=1 to configure again de certificates. When I choose the project, iOS platform, then the page to add p12 certificates files. The web shows an error in the upload section and it seems it doesn't work well.

How could renew the gym certificates for iOS platform?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to this in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), which would require you to migrate your GCM project to Firebase first.

Comment: Thanks to answer. But, I have 16 applications and

Comment: Thanks to answer to me. But, I have 16 applications and I want only renew the certificates. I don't want change any source code. The applications are in productions and now push notifications doesn't work. The web page https://developers.google.com/mobile/add shows an error and shows the popups.

[Wrong page to update certificates][1]

Comment: You're *not* going to migrate the code, you'll only *import the project*. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710079/4625829).

Comment: My applications are builded with html+js+css+cordova. The GCM code is done with JS and I use a plugin to receive push notifications. How could I migrate all? the link https://console.firebase.google.com/ doesn't work for me. Maybe my User has not login in yet.

Comment: Regardless of whichever client app you have, it doesn't need to change AFAIK. You have to manually import each project, which is by clicking on the *Import Google Project* in the Firebase Console.

Comment: Then, what things do I import to Firebase Console?

Comment: Ok. I see. I have imported one of my applications to test. After I have imported it... Do I need to do anything else? I mean, activate the message service o something more?

Comment: I have imported the project, updated the APN's certificates and I tried to send a message "Message Complete". But I haven't receive any message. I think I have to change all aplications. I suppose I have to change the Cordova GCM PLugin for Cordova FCM Plugin and the code.

Comment: Odd. If it shows that the message was sent, then it should work as usual, since FCM is backwards compatible.

Comment: It doesn't work. Have I changed the version of https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push? Have I updated the aplication?

Comment: You mentioned that you were using a plugin. You could try using a latest version if they have one for FCM.